# problem on Cauchy problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, cauchy-problem

$y u_x-xu_y=0,u=g $ on $ \Omega $ has a unique solution in neighborhood of $\Omega$ for every differentiable function g: $\Omega \rightarrow R$ if

1.$\Omega =\{(x,0):x>0\}$

2.$\Omega =\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=1\}$

3.$\Omega =\{(x,y):x+y=1,x>1\}$

4.$\Omega =\{(x,y):y=x^2,x>0\}$

What i have tried
 I use  Lagrange's method 
$$\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{dy}{-x}=\frac{du}{0}$$
$\implies u=c_1,x^2+y^2=c_2$

Solution is of the form $u= \phi(x^2+y^2)$ where $\phi$ has to be match with condition  given . For  option 1 after apply condition 
$g= \phi (x^2)$ $\implies \phi(x)= g(√x)$

solution becomes $u = g(√x^2+y^2)$ 
So option 1 looks correct to me

**for option 2**
After apply  condition

$g= \phi(1)$   from this i got no solution option 2 looks wrong to me

I am stuck at   3rd and 4th option please help me for these and also check my explanation for option 1and 2 . or **is there other method to solve such problems**

Answer (score 1):

In case 2) you can only get solutions if $g$ is constant on the unit circle, and then one has infinitely many solutions. So there is never a unique solution.

In case 3) the only point of tangency to a characteristic circle would be at $x=y=\frac12$ which is not on the ray. Thus you can parametrize a neighborhood of the ray using circle segments or the full circles $x^2+y^2=r^2$, $r>1$.

In case 4), the parabolic segment is likewise perpendicular to the characteristic circles, thus giving a unique solution on $\Bbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}%$